# Javascript Loop and filter out the data thats null or empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some data and I need to filter out the data thats null or empty and create a new data list thats filtered.

In this case sometimes "names" array is null so I need that data out.

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "description": "desc here",
            "names": [
                {

                    "name": "name here",
                },
                {

                    "name": "name here",
                }
            ],
            "other": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "200",
            "description": "desc here",
            "names": null
            "other": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "64",
            "description": "desc here",
            "names": [
                {

                    "name": "name here",
                },
                {

                    "name": "name here",
                }
            ],
            "other": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the arrays and objects recursive until a primitive is found. Then check and return the value.

```js
function copy(object) {
    var o;
    if (Array.isArray(object)) {
        return object.reduce(function (r, a) {
            var v = copy(a);
            v.names !== null && v.names !== '' && r.push(v);
            return r;
        }, []);
    }
    if (object !== null && typeof object === 'object') {
        o = {};
        Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
            o[k] = copy(object[k]);
        });
        return o;
    }
    return object;
}

var data = { people: [{ id: "2", description: "desc here", names: [{ id: "345", name: "name here", }, { id: "54", name: "name here", foo: "", }], other: "0" }, { id: "2", description: "desc here", names: null, other: "0" }, { id: "64", description: "desc here", names: [{ id: "87", name: "name here", }, { id: "53", name: "name here", }], other: "1" }] },
    result = copy(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works well but if names = null on a record I need the whole record removed from the new list. For example ..in my data above record id 200 would not appear at all in the new array

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = oldArray.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
```

Comment: You should add a description to your answer instead of just posting one line of code so that the OP learns *why* you are recommending this, otherwise it tends to lead to people just copying and pasting code without understanding what it does.

Answer (score -1):

```
new_array=yourObject.people.filter(function(elem){
 return elem.names!==null && elem.names!==""
});
```

Comment: This seems to be working but why does it show up in chrome as Object, Object, Object, Object]  and not as the original Object {people: Array[16]}  ?

Comment: After the filtering it seems to change and the rest of me code gives errors. Why doesn't it show like this anymore after filtering? Object {people: Array[16]}   ...it shows like this now: Object, Object, Object, Object]  ... converted?

Comment: it console written